# Passing 2 sets of data using JQuery .Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a search box:

```
<input class="box" name="search" type="text" id="search_input" />
```

And a `json_encode` array called `$findall`. Using jQuery `$.ajax()` I want to be able to pass the array AND the "keyword" from the input via the data field.  The code below has set the keyword from the search_input as the variable dataString

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "core/functions/searchdata.php",
                data: dataString,  
        //data:{availableDevicesArray : availableDevices },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('input#search_input').addClass('loading');
                },
                success: function(server_response) {
                    $('#searchresultdata').append(server_response);
                    $('span#category_title').html(search_input);
                }
```

I can pass either dataString or the array, but not both which I need.  How is it possible to pass them both?

UPDATE:

My PHP to get the array is:

```
mysql_select_db($database_database_connection, $database_connection);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Device_tbl";
$result=mysql_query($query, $database_connection) or die(mysql_error());
$findall = array ();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $findall[] = $row;
}
```

and I am storing the availbleDevices array like so:

```
var availableDevices = <? echo json_encode($findall); ?>;
```

Comment: Of course you can do `data: {data: dataString, availableDevices: availableDevices}` if they are in the proper format. jQuery takes care of encoding them.

Comment: I've tried that, it passes the array fine, just not the string.  I am using **data: { string: dataString** though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object and push these variables as its properties:

```
data: {
    'string' : 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    'array' : [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can I use variables for the string and array?  I tried 'string' : dataString, 'array' : {availableDevicesArray : availableDevices }

Comment: @K20GH This way You would have to do it this way: `'string' : dataString, 'array' : availableDevices` OR `'string' : dataString, 'availableDevicesArray' : availableDevices`.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume I am outputting this correctly then: '$myArray = $_REQUEST['availableDevicesArray'];
echo json_encode($myArray);'

Comment: @shadyx - Odd...  I've updated my question to reflect how I am getting the array and how I am storing it.  Regardless, the keyword doesn't get passed either

Comment: @K20GH And when You look into Your browser using FireBug or other development tool, how is the `var availableDevices = ...` written in JavaScript?

Comment: I've updated your answer to show the array.  There seems to be a lot of duplication for some reason